# Асоц массивы php

Tags: php

```
$out = Array ( 
      [orders] => Array ( 
         [0] => Array ( 
              [id] => 14138  
              [likes_all] => 35356 
              [likes_remain] => 11621 
              [item] => Array ( 
                       [item_id] => 368395724 
                       [album] => profile 
                       [img_src] => https://pp.vk.me/c837331/v837331336/1bbef/c8lXmmfhlp4.jpg ) 
                       [user] => Array ( [uid] => 178515510 ) ) 
         [1] => Array ( 
               [id] => 79931 
               [likes_all] => 25753 
               [likes_remain] => 7475 
               [item] => Array ( 
                        [item_id] => 411939044 
                        [album] => profile [img_src] => https://pp.vk.me/c837331/v837331336/1bbef/c8lXmmfhlp4.jpg ) 
                        [user] => Array ( [uid] => 178515510 ) 
         ) ) )
```

Как через foreach вывести элементы массива ?

Comment: Только минуса ставить умеете

Comment: +))
Зачем Вам while? foreach подойдет?

Comment: Да, вот только задачу чуть чуть поменялась

Comment: Измените вопрос

Comment: Уже изменил....

Comment: как у вас массив называется?

Comment: Без разницы, пусть будет $out

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1):

Если в основном массиве один элемент 'orders':

```
foreach ($out['orders'] as $order) {
    echo $order['likes_all'] . '<br>';
    echo $order['likes_remain'] . '<br>';
    echo $order['item']['img_src'] . '<br>';    
}
```

Если в основном массиве много элементов и 'orders' только один из них:

```
foreach ($out as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ':<br>'; // 'orders:'
    foreach ($value as $el)
        echo $el['likes_all'] . '<br>';
        echo $el['likes_remain'] . '<br>';
        echo $el['item']['img_src'] . <br>;
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял, у Вас массив в массиве.
В первом foreach вы получаете доступ к [orders], во втором foreach Вы [orders] листаете и получаете доступ к  likes_all,likes_remain и в последнем достаем img_src.

Документация доступна на русском по [ссылке](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp).
Попробуйте так:

```
foreach ($out as $my_array) {
    foreach ($my_array['orders'] as $order) {
        echo $order['likes_all'];
        echo $order['likes_remain '];
           foreach ($order['item'] as $item) {
              echo $item['img_src'];
           }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: orders

Comment: что у Вас есть в первом массиве ? Есть  [orders]?

Comment: Ну да, так как в вопросе у меня массив

Comment: Мне нужно likes_all,likes_remain и img_src

Comment: добавил читаемость в Ваш вопрос, структура верная?

Comment: Да верная......

Comment: img_src Находится в [item] смотрите внимательнее

Comment: Поправил и добавил ссылку на документацию